# dependency problem when deploying an .ear file in jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss6.x

I didn't know how much higher should I go,here is just a couple of lines more and I hope It helps:

It's good to have you guys here :-)

```
09:56:25,959 WARN  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] InitialContext did not implement EventContext
```

09:56:25,959 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
09:56:26,026 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=PersistenceManager,service=EJB3
09:56:26,031 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.PersistenceManager ejbName: PersistenceManager
09:56:26,035 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceManager/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceManager/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.IPersistenceManager - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,066 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TerminalDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,067 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.TerminalDL ejbName: TerminalDL
09:56:26,072 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TerminalDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TerminalDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ITerminalDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,073 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=OrganizationDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,074 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.OrganizationDL ejbName: OrganizationDL
09:56:26,086 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TerminalBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,086 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.TerminalBL ejbName: TerminalBL
09:56:26,093 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TerminalBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TerminalBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ITerminalBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,097 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/OrganizationDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/OrganizationDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.IOrganizationDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,098 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyReceiptItemDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,099 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.LoyaltyReceiptItemDL ejbName: LoyaltyReceiptItemDL
09:56:26,105 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyReceiptItemDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyReceiptItemDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ILoyaltyReceiptItemDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,106 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyReceiptDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,107 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.LoyaltyReceiptDL ejbName: LoyaltyReceiptDL
09:56:26,113 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyReceiptDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyReceiptDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ILoyaltyReceiptDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,115 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardAcceptorDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,115 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.CardAcceptorDL ejbName: CardAcceptorDL
09:56:26,121 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=ReceiptBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,122 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.ReceiptBL ejbName: ReceiptBL
09:56:26,128 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ReceiptBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ReceiptBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.IReceiptBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,133 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardAcceptorDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardAcceptorDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ICardAcceptorDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,134 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardHolderDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,135 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.CardHolderDL ejbName: CardHolderDL
09:56:26,140 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardAcceptorBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,141 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.CardAcceptorBL ejbName: CardAcceptorBL
09:56:26,146 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardAcceptorBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardAcceptorBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ICardAcceptorBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,151 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardHolderDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardHolderDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ICardHolderDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,152 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=UserDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,153 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.UserDL ejbName: UserDL
09:56:26,158 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.IUserDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,160 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=SystemPasswordDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,160 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.SystemPasswordDL ejbName: SystemPasswordDL
09:56:26,172 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardHolderBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,173 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.CardHolderBL ejbName: CardHolderBL
09:56:26,178 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardHolderBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardHolderBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ICardHolderBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,180 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=UserBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,180 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.UserBL ejbName: UserBL
09:56:26,188 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=PointCalculatorParsisBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,189 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.PointCalculatorParsisBL ejbName: PointCalculatorParsisBL
09:56:26,194 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/PointCalculatorParsisBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/PointCalculatorParsisBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.IPointCalculatorBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,200 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.IUserBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,203 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SystemPasswordDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SystemPasswordDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ISystemPasswordDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,204 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=UserSessionDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,205 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.UserSessionDL ejbName: UserSessionDL
09:56:26,210 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserSessionDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserSessionDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.IUserSessionDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,212 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=OrganizationEmployeeDL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,213 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.OrganizationEmployeeDL ejbName: OrganizationEmployeeDL
09:56:26,221 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=UserSessionBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,221 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.UserSessionBL ejbName: UserSessionBL
09:56:26,227 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserSessionBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserSessionBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.IUserSessionBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,233 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=AuthenticationBL,service=EJB3
09:56:26,234 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.impl.AuthenticationBL ejbName: AuthenticationBL
09:56:26,238 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AuthenticationBL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AuthenticationBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.IAuthenticationBL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,241 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/OrganizationEmployeeDL/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/OrganizationEmployeeDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.IOrganizationEmployeeDL - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,278 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
09:56:26,331 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=HolderWS,service=EJB3
09:56:26,332 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.ws.holder.HolderWS ejbName: HolderWS
09:56:26,335 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HolderWS/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HolderWS/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.holder.service.IHolderWS - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,341 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CmsWS,service=EJB3
09:56:26,342 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.ws.cms.CmsWS ejbName: CmsWS
09:56:26,346 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CmsWS/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CmsWS/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.cms.service.ICmsWS - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,358 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=AcceptorWS,service=EJB3
09:56:26,358 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.ws.acceptor.AcceptorWS ejbName: AcceptorWS
09:56:26,361 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

```
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AcceptorWS/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AcceptorWS/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.acceptor.service.IAcceptorWS - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

09:56:26,809 INFO  [service] Removing bootstrap log handlers
09:56:27,196 ERROR [org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap] Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$CardBL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$LoyaltyOperationsBL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyOperationsBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$TransactionBL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$TransactionReverseBL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionReverseBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$CardDL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardDL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$LoyaltyTransactionDL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyTransactionDL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$TransactoinReverseDL" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactoinReverseDL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "auto-timer-initializer:vfs:///E:/Shahab/Develop/jboss-6/server/default/deploy/webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/$PosWS" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=PosWS,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardBL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ICardDL' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardBL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyOperationsBL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.RandomGenerator' **")
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ICardBL' **")
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TransactionBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ITransactionBL' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyOperationsBL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyOperationsBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionBL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyTransactionDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ILoyaltyTransactionDL' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionBL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionReverseBL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TransactoinReverseDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ITransactoinReverseDL' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionReverseBL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-bl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactionReverseBL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardDL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.PersistenceManager' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardDL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=CardDL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyTransactionDL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.RandomGenerator' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyTransactionDL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=LoyaltyTransactionDL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactoinReverseDL,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.PersistenceManager' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactoinReverseDL,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-dl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TransactoinReverseDL,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=PosWS,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyOperationsBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ILoyaltyOperationsBL' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=PosWS,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=webservice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=PosWS,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "PreInstall")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ICardDL' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.PersistenceManager' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.RandomGenerator' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyTransactionDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ILoyaltyTransactionDL' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.PersistenceManager' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TransactionBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ITransactionBL' **, ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/CardBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ICardBL' **, ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.RandomGenerator' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LoyaltyOperationsBL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.bl.interf.ILoyaltyOperationsBL' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:webservice-product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TransactoinReverseDL/local-com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.interf.ITransactoinReverseDL' **

```
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.0.Alpha7]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.0.0.20100911-M5]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:118) [:0.1.0.Alpha1]
at
```

Comment: You'll need to go up higher in the logs for the actual errors. These are summaries only that are displayed after the server has finished its initialization. There are probably some full stack traces up there; we'll need to see those before we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be specific, but it looks like your .ear file is missing some necessary classes:

```
UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.dl.impl.PersistenceManager'
UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.raqamsazan.loyalty.webservice.api.RandomGenerator'
```

... and so on.

First thing to check is that your Maven build doesn't list the artifact(s) with these classes as "provided" or "test" or something like that (I'm assuming you're using Maven based on the artifact versioning scheme). Only certain scopes will cause Maven to include the dependency in your artifact.

Next thing to check is that the dependent classes have access to the dependency classes. For instance, a class in an .ejb jar can't see a class in your .war, but the reverse is OK.

If you get past those checks and are still having problems, you might need to dig into some [advanced JBoss classloading stuff](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration), or take a hard look at the structure of your application.

Comment: I am getting this `UNRESOLVED Demands` issue during server startup, before 2-3 days it used to work. Today suddenly it's started behaving like this. I didn't made any change that will affect class loading. I am using `Ivy` for build purpose